# Hosting a website on GitHub and connecting to a database

Tags: github

I apologize for the amateur nature of my question, but I am all rather new to this. So I have created a project within the cloud9 IDE, which is a website that connects to a mySQL database located on the same server. However, I wish to showcase the code that I have used to create the site. I have done a little research into doing this and so far I have found that GitHub Pages can allow you to host webcontent. Thus in theory I can just copy across the files from cloud9 to a GitHub repository. However, my site relies on being able to connect to and query a mySQL database. My question is, can and how would I connect my GitHub repo to such a database?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated! In addition, please let me know if I am barking up the wrong tree with this...

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Pages are only for static HTML websites. It does not run any server side technology.

You must find web hosting based on the technology you used to create the website.

Comment: Could I ask what you think would be the best way to demonstrate the code that you have used to build the site then?

Comment: Use your Github repo to display the code (Github Pages is a separate thing); use another service to host the app... like AWS, Heroku, many more...

Answer (score -1):

If you've been working on a server-side technology, then you could be running on localhost.
If thats the case, try tunnelling your localhost, which allows you to share your localhost with others on other networks.
localtunnel, ngrok and forward provide such technologies.